# Wrap Figure Issues and alignment

Tags: wrapfigure, alignment

I am trying to write a digest paper in one column format using IEEE template. I am trying to wrap figures around text and it is creating gaps where it shouldn't and for some reason, some places have started to revert back to two column format. Is there any fix for this? Also, I am an absolute beginner in LATEX, so bear with me.

What I've done is this:

I've invoked the one column mode by doing the following.

\documentclass[journal, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}

Then I wrapped the figures by doing the following:

```
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{bibtex/figures/PPU_Issue.png}
    \caption{Floating ground issue in inductor coupled PPU configuration}
    \label{ppu_old}    
\end{wrapfigure}
```

The resultant was as follows,
[image]

What I wanted was a one column type format. But the entire text shifted to two columns. Also, the image looks way off. Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks in advance and happy new year!

Comment: wrapfig has no `[h!]` option, but aprat from that as you have provided no example code it is very hard to help

Comment: So, how do I share the code? Do I have to provide access to the entire document?

Comment: No just a minimal working example. A compilable example starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document} and that reproduces the problem you are facing

Comment: why are you using IEEE class with a one-column format? Is there an IEEE journal that uses that format?

Comment: No. IEEE Journals are normally in two-column format. I was using the journal format with one column. Is that a wrong way to do things?

Answer (score 0):

An answer based on @David Carlisle comment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
  \usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text


  \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{bibtex/figures/PPU_Issue.png}
    \caption{Floating ground issue in inductor coupled PPU configuration}
    \label{ppu_old}    
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It fixed the two columns to one column transition but I don't want to fill any text. Rather, I'm running on space issues. How would you suggest to get the same one column format without using lipsum?

Comment: @Kaki_Res no _real_ document uses lipsum! that is just filler text for examples, instead of the actual text of your document., it is not really related to the answer at all.

Comment: Oh, I see! This should explain what level of a noob I am! Thanks again for the clarification. So, how can I fix the issue? I am using IEEE class in one column format because what I am writing is a Digest for peer review and not a journal paper.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, for your valuable suggestions. Turns out that my issue was solved by appropriate usage of the `\onecolumn` keyword wherever necessary. Also, the widths and sizes of images had to be readjusted to get the correct formatting.

Comment: Well, can you please add an MWE to show the solution? As it stands now your answer is no answer. Or consider to delete the question if you do not want to show code ...